# XQuery dynamic type mismatch

Tags: xml, oracle

I'm trying to run the code below:

```
with example(yourdata) as (  
select a.XMLRECORD from "FBNK_EB_CONTRACT_BA001" a)  
select row_id,amount,amtval from example,  
    xmltable(  
        'for $r in /row  
            let $rowid := $r/@id  
            for $c2 in $r/c2  
                let $m2 := $c2/@m  
                let $c5 := $r/c5[@m=$m2]  
                where exists($c5)  
                    return <amt> {$rowid} {$c2} {$c5} </amt>'  
    passing yourdata  
    columns  
        row_id varchar2(30)  PATH '@id',  
        amount varchar2(30) path 'c2',  
        amtval varchar2(30) path 'c5'  
    ) where amount IN ('CURACCOUNT','DUEACCOUNT')
```

However, I am getting the following error:

**ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence
19279. 00000 -  "XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence"
*Cause:    The XQuery sequence passed in had more than one item.
*Action:  Correct the XQuery expression to return a single item sequence.**

The data being returned by `select a.XMLRECORD from "FBNK_EB_CONTRACT_BA001" a` is as follows:

```
<row id="123456">

   <c1>USD</c1>

   <c2>AMOUNTS</c2>

   <c2 m="2">AMOUNT1</c2>

   <c2 m="3">AMOUNT2</c2>

   <c2 m="4">AMOUNT3</c2>

   <c2 m="5">AMOUNT4</c2>

   <c3 m="6" />

   <c4 m="7" />

   <c5>50000000</c5>

   <c5 m="2">2000000</c5>

   <c5 m="3">15000000</c5>

   <c5 m="4">2000000</c5>

   <c5 m="5">538773.07</c5>

    ....

    ....

</row>
<row id="789012">

   <c1>USD</c1>

   <c2>AMOUNTS</c2>

   <c2 m="2">AMOUNT1</c2>

   <c2 m="3">AMOUNT2</c2>

   <c2 m="4">AMOUNT3</c2>

   <c2 m="5">AMOUNT4</c2>

   <c3 m="6" />

   <c4 m="7" />

   <c5>50000000</c5>

   <c5 m="2">2700000</c5>

   <c5 m="3">14000</c5>

   <c5 m="4">2004500</c5>

   <c5 m="5">538776</c5>

    ....

    ....

</row>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggest, one of your selections return more than one element.

You have to check your complete XML file to see where is the problem.

One possible cause of troubles would be such data

```
   <c5 m="5">538773.07</c5>
   <c5 m="5">999999.07</c5>
```

Note the duplicated attribute `m`.

To check if this is the case simple update the `let` statement considering only the second element -  add the `[2]` :

```
 let $c5 := $r/c5[@m=$m2][2]
```

If the XQUERY returns something - you see immediately which ID is wrong. If you get nor result, check analogously the `c2`.

Also strange - in your sample data the element `row` seems not to be the root element which is processed in your XQUERY `for $r in /row`; but this is probably typo...

Comment: My data is actually coming like in the sample I gave. Should the XQuery be modified?

Comment: OK, if the table `FBNK_EB_CONTRACT_BA001`contains several rows and in each row there is XML `<row> ... </row>` this is fine; forget my last remark of missig root element.